# Let $S$ be a finite set. Show that any function $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous on S. What if $S$ is countably infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I struggling with R.K. Sundaram 1.7.43 exercise:

Let $S$ be a finite set. Show that any function $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous on S. What if $S$ is countably infinite?

I saw that by [this page](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch7.pdf) the definition of continuity is simple, but i'm havind douts with finite set definition.

Any thought would be appreciated.

tks

Comment: Is $S$ a subset of the reals with the usual metric?

Comment: The exercise doesn't let it be clear, but i think it so.

Comment: Can you find an open set around a point in $S$ that does not contain any other points in $S$?

Comment: I think S could be any finite  with a metric.  The comment about depending on the topology pertains to topologies with distance functions that are not metrics.  If S $\subset$ X a metric, the result holds though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $S$ is finite, there is a minimum distance between elements, call this $D$.

Take some $x_0 \in S$. Suppose $\epsilon>0$. Let $\delta = \dfrac{D}{2}$. If $|x-x_0|<\delta$, you must have $x=x_0$. So $f(x)=f(x_0)$ and so $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f(x)-f(x)|=0 < \epsilon$.

This means that $f$ is continuous at each $x_0$ (in fact, uniformly continuous).

If you let $S$ be infinite, this minimum distance may no longer exist. So the above argument doesn't work.

In fact, it's easy enough define a discontinuous function with a countable domain. Take for example: $f(1/n)=1/n$ for all $n=1,2,\dots$ and let $f(0)=123$.

The domain of $f$ is $\left\{\dfrac{1}{n} \;\Bigg|\; n=1,2,3,\dots \right\} \cup \{0\}$. It isn't hard to prove $f$ is discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: Nice @BillCook, the finite definition, is the key of prove. Tks, for help me again.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ with the induced metric, $S$ is a hausdorff space. In particular, it is $\tau_1$. Since it is finite, every set is a complement of a finite set, which is a finite union of points (which are closed), hence every set is open. Therefore, the topology is discrete. Hence, every function from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (in fact, any space) is continuous.

For a counter-example to the enumerable case, take for instance $S=\{\frac{1}{n}\}\cup \{0\}$. It is easy to see that $f$ defined as $1$ in each $\frac{1}{n}$ and $0$ in $0$ is not continuous.

Comment: tks @AloizioMacedo!

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n$ be a sequence such that $x_n\to x$. Then,obviously, $x_n$ remains a constant after finite terms, that is, $\exists ~N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=x_0$ for all $n\geq N$. Therefore, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$