# About the definition of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following problem:

Let $ D=\lbrace x_{1} \dots x_{n}  \rbrace$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Proof that every function $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

and following definition for continuous functions:

Let $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function and let $a \in D$. Than $f$ is called continuous at $a$ if: Is $ $($ a_{n} $)$ $ a sequence in $D$, which converges to $a$, then the sequence $(f(a_{n})$ converges to $ f(a) $. The function $f$ is called continuous on $D$ if $f$ is continuous at each $a\in D.$

Just to get an idea of how to tackle this problem I took the function $\operatorname{sign}(x)$ ($1$ for $x>0$, $0$ for $x=0$ and $-1$ for $ x<0$) which is NOT continuous and a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$, for example $D=\lbrace -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 \rbrace$. According to the problem it should be possible to show that the function is continuous for the chosen $D$. 
So I think what kind of sequence I could choose. Here the issues starts. Can I "define" a sequence in $D$ like $-2,-1,0,1,2$ which has the limit $3$? Or what would be a possible sequence? As far as I understood, I can only use elements from $D$ for the sequence members and the limit?!

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $S$ be a finite set. Show that any function $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous on S. What if $S$ is countably infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483269/let-s-be-a-finite-set-show-that-any-function-f-s-rightarrow-mathbbrn)

Answer (score 3):

You don't *choose* a sequence; you take *any* sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ which converges to some $d\in D$, and you prove that $f(d)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)$. That is easy. Take$$\varepsilon=\min\bigl\{|d-d'|:d'\in D\setminus\{d\}\bigr\}.$$There is a $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies|a_n-d|<\varepsilon$. But then $n\geqslant N\implies a_n=d$ and therefore $n\geqslant N\implies f(a_n)=f(d)$. So, $f(d)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)$ indeed.

Answer (score 1):

See the definition for convergence: A sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ is said to converge to a real number $a$ if for any $\epsilon >0$, there is a natural number $N$ such that whenever $n > N$, then $|a_n -a|<\epsilon$. In other words, $(a_n)$ converges to $a$ when for any small distance $\epsilon$, the terms of $a_n$ are all (after a certain $N$) within that $\epsilon$ distance of $a$.

Now can you reason out that the only way a sequence $(a_n)$ with terms from a finite set $D$ can converge is if the sequence is eventually constant?

Further, for a function $f; D \to \mathbb R$ to be continuous, for *any* convergent sequence $(a_n) \longrightarrow a$ in $D$, $f(a_n)$ converges to $f(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon >0$ be given.  Let $ \delta < \min_{i \neq j} |x_i - x_j|$. Then for any $x_0 \in D$, the set of points $x' \in D$ such that $|x'-x|< \delta$ includes only $x_0$. Then $|f(x_0)-f(x')| < \varepsilon$ for all $x'$ such that $|x'-x|<\delta$, so $f$ is continuous.